# Integration of JSF with Spring Security

Tags: hibernate, jsf, spring-security

Sorry for my English. Problem in integration of JSF with Spring Security.

What I did:

1. In entity `User` implemented interface `UserDetails`
2. Interface `UserDAO` extends interface `UserDetailsService`
3. `UserHibernateDAO` implemented interface `UserDAO`

   In LoginMB if to add metod `login()`:

   ```
   public void login() {
           UserDetails user = getDao().loadUserByUsername("admin2@admin.ru");
           password= user.getPassword();
   }
   ```

   Then displays the password as expected, that is, steps 1-3 are working.
4. In applicationContext-security.xml I to add:

   ```
   <beans:bean id="UserDAO" class="com.otv.model.dao.hibernate.UserHibernateDAO" />
   <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
       <authentication-provider user-service-ref="UserDAO" />
   </authentication-manager>
   ```
5. In LoginMB:

   ```
   public class LoginMB implements Serializable {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
       AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

       private String userName;
       private String password;

       public String login() {

           UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("admin2@admin.ru", "2");

           // next line is 54 
           Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);            

           if (authenticate.isAuthenticated()) {
               SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
           }
           return "success";
       }

       //get and set metods

   }
   ```

It prints the error:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: #{loginMB.login}: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.otv.managed.bean.LoginMB.login(LoginMB.java:54)
```

How I think, in LoginMB do not work `@Qualifier` annotation:

```
@Qualifier("authenticationManager")
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

Please tell me how then on another link authenticationManager?

Comment: Please update the question to show just the question. Move the *problem solved* section into an answer and wait for two days to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From applicationContext-security.xml do not work `@ManagedProperty`. Why?

1. In LoginMB I added:

   ```
   @ManagedProperty(value="#{authenticationManager}")
   AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
   ```
2. In applicationContext.xml I added:

   ```
   <sec:http auto-config="true">

       <sec:form-login login-page="/pages/login.html" authentication-failure-url="/fail.html" />
       <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/service/*" access="ROLE_SHIPPER" />
       <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/task/*" access="ROLE_CARRIER" />

   </sec:http>

   <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
       <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="UserDAO">
           <sec:password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
       </sec:authentication-provider>
   </sec:authentication-manager>
   ```

It is working!